# populate select tag in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a many masters in my project of the basic one is country,state and city.
i have added/inserted the records in mysql database but when i want to edit record how can i populate the state select tag when the country is selected from mysql database?

For example i have a record in city table as

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════
║ COUNTRY║  STATE║ CITY ║
╠========╬══════════════╬
║  INDIA ║ PUNJAB║ ABC  ║
║  INDIA ║ J&K   ║ PQR  ║
║  USA   ║ NJ    ║ MNO  ║
=========================
```

NOW when i go for edit operation for say suppose record 1 i.e INDIA-PUNJAB-ABC

I am able to select INDIA in Country select tag but i am not able to get only INDIA states and select ABC in select tag of state

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: try to use DISTINCT: SELECT DISTINCT(country), city WHERE country = 'india'

Comment: Are you trying to add selected attribute in dropdrown ? or can not assign value based on the country ?

Comment: @Daimos DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

However you achieve this, you will need to interrogate the db using the selected COUNTRY.  So..

1. Option 1 :perform an AJAX request 'onChange' of the COUNTRY to populate the CITY  box using Javascript
2. Option 2 : refresh/submit the page 'onChange'of the COUNTRY and use the posted COUNTRY field to generate a filtered list of CITY options to use in the

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data.
You need tables country and state.
And in your table use city_id and state_id or only state_id.